# Laravel Eloquent - Exclusive transaction.

Tags: php, transactions, laravel-4, locking, eloquent

I have a table, with two columns, A and B. The set (A, B) is unique, but B alone is not. Whenever I add a row to the table, I want B to get the next available number - so if the table has:

```
A   B
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
2   3
```

Then next row inserted would have B = 3 if A = 1, and B = 4 if A = 2.

So, given an A, I need to select MAX(B)  from the table to know what the new value should be, and then run the insert. However, I want to avoid the case where two instances of the script get the same value for B, so I need to get an exclusive lock on the table before running the select and insert as a single transaction.

The only alternative I can think of is to write a raw database query doing an insert...select, as eloquent does not support that. I'd rather use an eloquent function if it is possible though. So is there any way to get an exclusive lock on a table from laravel?

This is nearly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180818/laravel-4-exclusive-transaction-with-update-and-select), but the accepted answer there is "do it a different way" and that won't work in this case.

Comment: if I understand well if two instances of the script get the same b values, they will also have the same (A,B) primary key and then the second one cannot be inserted and an exception will be thrown. right?

Comment: @momo Right. And catching the exception is an option, but not the ideal one - I would much rather not have it thrown in the first place.

Comment: What storage engine does your table use?

Comment: @eggyal InnoDB. Is that relevant though? The question is about Eloquent functions.

Comment: It's relevant because [MyISAM can provide such functionality natively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12878700).